Different Complexity Measures for Formulas
There are various ways to define complexity measures for formulas.
One is like: $C(a \lor b) = \max(C(a), C(b)) + 1, \cdots$.
Another is like: $C(a \lor b) = C(a) + C(b) + 1, \cdots$.
Could you kindly provide some examples that demonstrate the differences between these approaches when applying them in induction? I think I have seen some examples before, but I can't recall them at the moment.

Usually you just want to prove in your inductive step that if something works for all the pieces of a formula, it works for the whole formula. In this case, the precise choice of complexity measure doesn't matter, as long as the pieces have lower complexity than the formula.
